# Wrapping a component in a forwardRef() ( experimenting a drag and drop library for React)

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to implement a list that is sortable in React with a drag and drop function.
In the main page they explicit says that this: "SortableItem
This component doesn't take any other props than its child. This child should be a single React element that can receives a ref. If you pass a component as a child, it needs to be wrapped with React.forwardRef()."  In my case I have exactly a seprate list component that is mapped, so I would need to wrap this component in a forwardRef. How's the best way to do this? This is my code:

```
   <SortableList onSortEnd={onSortEnd} className="list" draggedItemClassName="dragged">
              {bundles && bundles.map((bundle) => (
                <SortableItem key={bundle.id}>
                <BundleView deleteBundle={deleteBundle} docId={docId} clickedBundleId={clickedBundleId} getBundleId={getClickedBundle} key={bundle && bundle.id} id={bundle && bundle.id} title={bundle && bundle.title} />
                </SortableItem>
              ))}
            </SortableList>
```

I guess the BundleView component needs to be wrapped into a forwardRef. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap `BundleView` like so:

```js
const BundleView = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const {deleteBundle, docId ...} = props

    // Your component code here

    // The passed ref should be forwarded to the base DOM element, for example
    return <div ref={ref}>{props.children}</div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm still not getting it. My BundleView is already a separate component that I import on this page. Shall I move all the code inside the const BundleView=React.forwardRef ?